How to remove the additional space above and below a `l3coffin` that was combined from an `amsthm` environment and a figure horizontally?
As the title described, I define an environment via l3coffins that can combine two parts horizontally. I used this environment to combine an amsthm and a figure, but there exists a gap before and after the whole coffin. How to solve this?
Additionally, I don't want to solve this via \vspace roughly, I prefer like to know the reason that caused the additionally vertical gaps. What's more, I have tried using \vspace, but I found that when I solved the gap between a coffin and a common text paragraph and the gap between a common text paragraph and a coffin, the gap between two nearest coffins was so tight.
The figure below is the measurement to the gaps before I used \vspace:

The figure below is the measurement to the gaps after I used \vspace, the gap between two coffins gets so tight:

The following is the MWE. The effect shows in the last screenshot is that I added \vspace{-6pt} before and \vspace{-4.5pt} after coffin_typeset.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer
  [ rightmargin, contents = \layercontentsmeasure
  ] {measurelayer}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{measurestyle}{measurelayer}
\pagestyle{measurestyle}

\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,lipsum,amsthm}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter

\coffin_new:N \l__skyrmion_textfig_main_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l__skyrmion_textfig_minor_coffin
\NewDocumentEnvironment{textfig}{O{2 \c_colon_str 1}}
  {
    \group_begin:
    \seq_set_split:Nee \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {\c_colon_str} {#1}
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l__skyrmion_textfig_main_coffin
      {
        \fp_eval:n
          {
            .96*\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {1}/
              (
                \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {1} + 
                \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {2}
              )
          }\dimexpr \linewidth
      }
  }
  {
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l__skyrmion_textfig_main_coffin {r}{vc}
                          \l__skyrmion_textfig_minor_coffin {l}{vc}
                            {.02\linewidth}{0pt}
    % \vspace{-6pt}
    \noindent
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l__skyrmion_textfig_main_coffin {l} {vc} {0pt} {0pt}
    % \vspace{-4.5pt}
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \textfigsplit {}
  {
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l__skyrmion_textfig_minor_coffin
      {
        \fp_eval:n
          {
            .96*\seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {2}/
              (
                \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {1} + 
                \seq_item:Nn \l__skyrmion_textfig_ratio_seq {2}
              )
          }\dimexpr \linewidth
      } 
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\begin{textfig}[1:1]
  \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{problem}
  \textfigsplit
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .6\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{textfig}

\begin{textfig}
  \begin{problem}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{problem}
  \textfigsplit
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = .8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{textfig}

\begin{problem}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{problem}

\end{document}


I think it is because the problem environment adds the usual vertical spacing above and below a list. when it isn't inside a coffin, this gets rolled into the space between lines/paragraphs. but when it is inside a coffin, it is fixed, so you get the interline spacing on top of the spacing above and below a list.

you could avoid this, maybe, by zapping that spacing within the box and adding it back outside it, so it would get rolled up with other vertical spacing according to the usual rules?
